# Text from selected item in DropDownList asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, pageload

In the pageload i populate a dropdownlist like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string buildingTypeSoldier = "soldier";
        var soldierBuilding = from b in dc.Buildings
                                 where b.buildingtype == buildingTypeSoldier
                                 select b.buildingname;
        ddlSoldierBuildings.DataSource =soldierBuilding;
        ddlSoldierBuildings.DataBind();
    }
```

But when i then try to set the text of a label on the same page to the selectetitem.text i only get the first item in the list, not the item i selected. I try to set the text by using a button like this:

```
protected void btnBuySoldierBuilding_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTestlabel.Text = ddlSoldierBuildings.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

the dropdownlist contains tree items, barracks, shooters range, and stable which i get from my database. Does the page load overwrite my selection when i click the button? How can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your `Page_Load` is firing before your event handler.

Wrap your `Page_Load` initialization logic inside an if block where you check if your page is handling a postback or not by checking the [`Page.IsPostback` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx).  If it's a postback, then your initialization logic won't fire and reset your drop down list.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostback){
        string buildingTypeSoldier = "soldier";
        var soldierBuilding = from b in dc.Buildings
                                 where b.buildingtype == buildingTypeSoldier
                                 select b.buildingname;
        ddlSoldierBuildings.DataSource =soldierBuilding;
        ddlSoldierBuildings.DataBind();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Great, this works. Thank you very much for such a fast answer!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the binding code above in an `if (!Page.IsPostBack) { }` block. Else you are losing your control state.