# asp.net dropdown list can't take text value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

in asp.net,i have a dropdown list and i fill it with values from 1 to 100.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="Product1dropdown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnProduct1Addtocart" runat="server" Text="Add to cart" onclick="btnAddtoChart1_Click" />

protected void btnAddtoChart1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Product1dropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

Whatever i select from dropdown list,it doesn't matter, label1.text always takes value '1' which is dropdown list's default value.Thanks for the help.

Comment: show dropdown population code

Comment: check "when" your page filled the ddl... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889971/text-from-selected-item-in-dropdownlist-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue.  When I use a text field for the dropdownlist (e.g. DataValueField="TextField") then it will not update and always returns the first item in the list as it's selected value, even when the user selects another option (which does at least update in the browser),   this is WEIRD!